# SQL Join to get most recent record

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three tables:

- `Measurements (MeasureID, Time, Distance, Value)`
- `Events(EventID, Time Value)`
- `EventValues (EventDataID, EventID, Type, Value)`

I need to get for every measurement, the most recent event (in the past) and its associated eventvalues data.

My current query is quite ugly:

```
SELECT 
    M.*,
    (SELECT TOP 1 EV.value FROM [Event] E JOIN EventValues EV ON E.EventID = EV.EventID 
     WHERE M.Time >= E.Time ORDER BY M.Time-E.Time) AS Data,
FROM [Measure] M 
ORDER BY M.Distance
```

and it only allows me to select one column from the `EventValues` table (I need more)

Is there any way this can be done using a join?

**EDIT**: I also need to select ALL entries from the measurement table even if they are before the first event (i.e. just select null data for the join)

Comment: How the tables of Measurements and Events are realted ? there is no foreign key, are they related via time value ?

Comment: If there was 2 EventValue records for a given most recent event, what is your expectation in that case? To see both records or just one of them? Also, are temp tables acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CROSS APPLY.

```
SELECT  
    M.*, Data.* 
FROM [Measure] M 
CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP 1 EV.* FROM [Event] E JOIN EventValues EV ON E.EventID = EV.EventID  
     WHERE M.Time >= E.Time ORDER BY E.Time DESC) AS Data
ORDER BY M.Distance
```

Comment: +1 This query (almost) works, thanks - however is there a way to include the entries from the measurement table that are BEFORE the first event

Comment: You can use OUTER APPLY instead of CROSS APPLY and you'll get NULLS for the "Data" (EventValues) columns.

Comment: Im accepting this answer over amit-g's as this performs better in my situation, although both produce the correct results.

Comment: Thanks.  I think both solutions are fine, and it's good to know about both techniques.  The perf difference may be that I changed the ORDER BY to "E.Time DESC" and amit_g used your expression.  Mine can take advantage of an index on E.Time so changing it in his solution (in the OVER clause) might give you the same performance.  Then you can use the one that you think is cleaner and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (not tested)

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT M.*, E.*, EV.EventDataID, EV.Type, EV.Value,
        Rank() over (Partition BY M.MeasureID order by M.Time - E.Time) as Rank
    FROM [Measure] M 
    INNER JOIN [Event] E ON M.Time >= E.Time
    INNER JOIN EventValues EV ON E.EventID = EV.EventID
) T
WHERE Rank = 1
```

**EDIT**

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT M.*, E.*, EV.EventDataID, EV.Type, EV.Value,
        Rank() over (Partition BY M.MeasureID order by M.Time - E.Time) as Rank
    FROM [Measure] M 
    LEFT JOIN [Event] E ON M.Time >= E.Time
    LEFT JOIN EventValues EV ON E.EventID = EV.EventID
) T
WHERE Rank = 1
```

Comment: +1 This query (almost) works, thanks - however is there a way to include the entries from the measurement table that are BEFORE the first event?