# SQL Server Ordering time by most recent, then closest

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have tables as posted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163091/sql-join-to-get-most-recent-record).

•Measurements (MeasureID, Time, Distance, Value)

•Events(EventID, Time Value)

•EventValues (EventDataID, EventID, Type, Value)

I currently can get the most recent events for each measurement, however what i would like to do is get the most recent event, but if one doesnt exist (i.e. the measurement is BEFORE the first event) i would like to get the CLOSEST event (so basically the first event)

I am thinking to maybe order by time difference showing positive times first then negative times last in my subquery, is this possible and how can i acheive it?

Comment: Is it too hard to copy/paste your tables into this question?

Comment: No, but the extra information there may be useful and i thought that was the correct procedure

Comment: Gotchya..my bad. You should've mentioned that xP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Havent tested, but I think something like the case logic below would work.

```
(SELECT TOP 1 EV.value FROM [Event] E JOIN EventValues EV ON E.EventID = EV.EventID 
  WHERE M.Time >= E.Time 
  ORDER BY case when M.Time > E.Time then 1 else 2 end, 
           abs(M.Time-E.Time)) AS Data
```

Comment: +1 Thanks, I just had to remove the WHERE clause and use DateDiff in the ABS function